# График полета летательного аппарата по баллистической траектории, не получается ввести новые переменные

Tags: python, математика, график, уравнения, система-уравнений

Необходимо построить график движения летательного аппарата согласно системе дифференциальных уравнений (рис 1):

[image: рисунок 1]

Есть код для построения функции только одной переменной вести новую со всеми зависимостями выдает ошибку. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно исправить ошибку:

[image: рисунок 3]

Необходимо получить график следующего вида (красная линия, что должно выйти):

[image: рисунок 2]

Нужно получить зависимость от нескольких переменных и получить баллистическую траекторию полета:

Мой код:

```
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
symbol_x = sp.Symbol('x')

def get_vector(a, b):
return np.arange(a, b , 0.1)
def plot_2d_function(function, a, b):
# Create the sympy function f(x)
f_x = sp.sympify(function)

# Create domain and image
domain_x = get_vector(a, b)
image = [f_x.subs(symbol_x, value) for value in domain_x]

# Plot the 2D function graph
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
plt.plot(domain_x, image)
plt.show()
function = "x*cos(x)"
a_value = 0
b_value = 10

plot_2d_function(function, a_value, b_value)
```

Comment: Где значения для *v* ?

Comment: Код, который вы приложили текстом, рисует фиксированную функцию. Задача, которую вы привели картинкой, про решение дифференциального уравнения. Это настолько разные задачи, что я не понимаю как вам помочь. Объяснить как численно решать (интегрировать) дифференциальные уравнения? Там одних разговоров на неделю. У меня ощущение что не понимаете про что спрашиваете. Например, забыты начальные условия.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, скорость от нуля и увеличивается до экстремума в верхней точке,значения я задам сам, главное алгоритм зависимости,чтобы с измененим тех параметров код считал х и у и я могу отобразить это на графике

Comment: Где "скорость от нуля и увеличивается до экстремума в верхней точке" в коде? Где зависимость между *v, x, y* ?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy,в этом то и дело что зависимость не могу построить сразу ошибку выдает если ввожу переменную дальности или. Высоты или скорости или угла,эти величины постоянно увеличиваться должны согласно системе дифф уравнений ,подскажите,пожалуйста , как внедрить.лишь картинкойуказал зависимости где у это высота н,х дальность l.

Comment: Ещё раз перечитайте мой длинный комментарий. Вам нужно решить сложную задачу. Вы не понимаете что это за задача. Если я решу задачу за вас, толку не будет ни мне ни вам. Открывайте учебник на главе "решение дифференциальных уравнений". Там вам объяснят, как задать уравнение, как задать начальные условия, как выполнить интегрирование. Здесь задавать вопросы рано.